# GetStringAsync being called from Xamarin Forms hangs (using emulator)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

New to Xamarin and calling API's I've got a simple webserver returning JSON that works in Postman. I have a dummy certificate so I can call using SSL, but when I reach the GetStringAsync method even after enabling TLS1.2 and making the async task my code just hangs.

I have this in my AndroidManifest

This is the output:

02-17 14:36:49.951 D/Mono    (31087): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
02-17 14:36:49.951 D/Mono    (31087): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
02-17 14:36:49.951 D/Mono    (31087): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
02-17 14:36:49.951 D/Mono    (31087): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
02-17 14:36:49.951 D/Mono    (31087): Probing '__android_log_print'.
02-17 14:36:49.951 D/Mono    (31087): Found as '__android_log_print'.
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087): Exception caught while cancelling connection: Java.Net.SocketException: Socket closed
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):   at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-29/mcw/Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection.cs:422
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.b__0 () [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:351
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):   --- End of managed Java.Net.SocketException stack trace ---
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:394)
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
02-17 14:36:49.956 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:182)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
02-17 14:36:49.957 I/monodroid-net(31087):

Comment: is your server public or local?  Have you verified connectivity from the device using the browser?

Comment: its on a IIS instance on the same box that has the xamarin emulator on it. I can hit it from postman but I get a message about an invalid ssl certificate but if I have postman not do the ssl validation I get a response. I can also hit the site directly from the browser with and without the https prefix

Comment: are you using the desktop browser, or the browser on the device emulator?

Comment: desktop browser, but I just tried the emulator browser. I see the problem, I gave the website a name and aliased it out in my etc/hosts file on the PC. Of course the device can't see that. How can I get the device to see my locally hosted IIS site?

Comment: generally you need to use the IP, not the name.  And you need to be sure your local IIS is configured to enable remote connections (it will see the emulator as a remote device)